# CIPixellate output image size is different

Tags: iphone, ios6, cifilter, imagefilter

I am using CIPixellate for pixelating image in ios6. It results in bigger image. How can I keep the original size?

```
    NSData *imageData   =  [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImageView.image, 1.0)];//[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedImageView.image)];
    beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer]];    
    filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPixellate" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputScale", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.0], nil];   
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];    
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];   
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
```

// new image is bigger in size and most part is cropped :-/

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = origim.imageOrientation;
CIImage *result = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:origim.CGImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIFilter *pixel = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPixellate"];
[pixel setDefaults];
[pixel setValue:result forKey:@"inputImage"];
[pixel setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:100.0 Y:100.0] forKey:kCIInputCenterKey];
[pixel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:yeslider.value] forKey:kCIInputScaleKey];
result = [pixel valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGImageRef imgRef = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:result.extent];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
```

In your code you’re creating your CGImage from a rect. You aren't using `.extent`. This causes your image’s original dimensions to be lost.